# Confusion regarding Async Servlet support in Spring 3.2.0.M1 and Jetty

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, jetty

[Spring 3.2.0.M1](http://www.springsource.org/node/3563) was released today with support for [asynchronous @Controller methods](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/). I'm trying to use this in an existing web app deployed as a war on Jetty. However, I've a few fundamental questions.

1. Do I need Jetty 8 OR this should run on Jetty 7 as well.
2. Is the async support build on top of Servlet 3.0 API or it is something that Spring MVC has implemented. In other words, do I need a Servlet 3.0 supported container for asynchronous controller to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the topic of Jetty, servlet 3.0 support is in Jetty 8.  You can not use jetty-7 as it implements only servlet 2.5 support.  You can get async behavior in jetty-7 through jetty-continuations but that is not the same api as in servlet 3.0.

So that is 1/2 an answer only, I can't speak to the spring side of things.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer to the second question here.http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/